# Redefinition of 'Comment' as different kind of symbol in swift

Tags: swift, core-data, symbols

I have a class `Comment` declared as such:

```
public class Comment: NSManagedObject {
    vars and methods...
}
```

When I try to compile my project, I get an error that reads:

> Redefinition of 'Comment' as different kind of symbol

It highlights this line in the generated `.h` file: `@interface Comment : NSManagedObject`, and it tells me that the original declaration of `Comment` is in `AIFF.h` (something part of Foundation) and the line of the declaration is: `typedef struct Comment                  Comment;`.

I've only recently gotten this problem, and I've built the project with a `Comment` object successfully before. Why would an error like this happen in Swift?

## Edit

If I remove the `NSManagedObject` superclass it compiles...

Answer (score 1):

It may be a case that your class `Comment` is defined somewhere else in Foundation framework. What you need to do is importing only specific classes that you need inside your file. First remove all `import` statements in the source file and then import `NSManagedObject` like this:

```
import class CoreData.NSManagedObject
```

Then you will gain access to the `NSManagedObject` class you need for your `Comment` subclass. If you need any classes or structs from `Foundation` framework (for example `NSError`) you should import them like this:

```
import class Foundation.NSError
```

This will eliminate compiler errors about redefinition of class `Comment`.

Also make sure to clean the project and clean build folder by using `Command + Shift + K` and `Command + Shift + alt + K`